# How do I setup an Azure Web Farm on multiple VM's using a shared IIS config

Tags: iis, azure, azure-virtual-machine, web-farm

I setup a VM running Windows Server 2012 R2 (VM1) and configured it to run IIS. I then created another VM in the same region off an image I made from the first (VM2). These two are in their own availability set located in the West US data center.

Assuming I want to share my IIS configuration and website files between the two servers, I need to setup a location to store and access these files regardless of what server is making changes to them or is online at the time.

Attached storage almost provides a solution, but this can only be tied to a single machine at a time. Files can be stored in a separate Blob storage, but I don't know how to get IIS to read and write to it.

Once I do figure out how to share these files in a manner IIS will accept, I have a second problem where I would need a third VM (VM3) in Europe that would need access to this data as well.

Thank you for any assistance anyone can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use DFS (Distributed File System) to accomplish this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753479(v=ws.10).aspx
http://blogs.iis.net/rickbarber/archive/2012/12/05/keeping-multiple-iis-7-servers-in-sync-with-shared-configuration.aspx

Thanks. 
-matt

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will take a look at that option today and let you know.

Comment: Sounds good. Let me know if there is anything else and if my answer addressed your issue ;)

Comment: Thanks Matt, we got it to work although it took a bit of setup to do. Based off your idea I found this tutorial that explained the whole setup on Azure pretty well. http://clemmblog.azurewebsites.net/high-available-file-share-in-windows-azure-using-dfs/

Comment: You can also try Azure File Sync now which is certainly a lot easier to setup and maintain, plus it backs up all your files to Azure File Storage..

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using something like Dropbox to keep the folders synchronized?

Comment: I have, but I'd like to keep the response times as low as possible.